# working with css to align center

Tags: html, css

I have a html file with a `div` tag and some text in that tag. I want to adjust that text exactly middle of div and also div exactly middle of page for any resolution. I tried it with `margin:0 auto` then it appears top center, but vertically it does not appear in middle.

Answer (score 3):

The div needs CSS like this, depending on the rest of your HTML:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
```

That will align the div in the centre of its container and align the text within it to the centre also.

Edit - I've just noticed you want to vertically centre the div too. There are lots of ways of doing this that a quick Google would show up, such as this method: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 2):

`margin auto 0` will work only only you give `width` to your `div`. `text-align:center` will align text in the center.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this, http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

To adjust your div use this code:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

And to make text in middle of div use this code:

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/KcrvL/.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the container div with the css like this:

```
div{
    margin: 0 auto; /*= the 0 sets the top and bottom margin to zero and the auto centers the div =*/
    width: 940px;   /*= the width is a must have but can be set to the size you need =*/
    text-align: center; /*= use this if you want to center the text inside the div =*/
}
```